# C++ pointers to vectors behavior

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

I know that using raw pointers on vectors is not the best way because of the smart ones,
but mine is just a question to understand something that I can't wrap my head around...
If a I create a vector and then a pointer to it:

```
    vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,4,5};
    vector<int> *ptr = &vec;
```

1. Why do i need to use the reference operator `&`
   whereas an array doesn't need it?? (aren't vectors dynamic arrays)
2. Why if i write `cout<<*ptr<<endl;`, compiler gives error and I have to write `cout<<(*ptr)[1]<<endl;` or `cout<< ptr->at(1)`??

Usually if you create a pointer to an array that pointer points to the first element.

Can you help me understand what kind of animal vectors are?

Comment: If you had created a pointer to array `int arr[20] = {1,2,3,4,5}; int (*ptr)[20] = &arr;` the two points above wouldn't apply either.

Comment: Vectors behave like dynamically allocated arrays, and internally they are dynamically allocated arrays. However, the key word there is "internally". You don't know that the pointer to the vector is also the pointer to the first vector element. You might be grabbing the internal size counter, or a pointer to the dynamic array, or any number of other "internal", implementation-defined values.

Comment: _Why do i need to use the reference operator(&) _. Well.. It isn't reference operator.. It's an _address-of operator_, which does, exactly as you want it to - takes the address of the `vec` variable.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do i need to use the reference operator(&) whereas an array
>   doesn't need it??(aren't vectors dynamic arrays)

The equivalent of what you've done, with arrays is this:

```
int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int (*ptr)[5] = &array; // less constrained to just 5 elements with vectors
```

So yea you still need the `&` operator;

> Why if i write `cout<<*ptr<<endl;`, compiler gives error and I have to
>   write `cout<<(*ptr)[1]<<endl;` or `cout<< ptr->at(1)`??

Because vectors are objects and the `*` operator was not overloaded to return anything useful apart from the vector itself.

---

What you probably want to do is to use the [`std::vector::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) function of vectors which gives you a pointer to the underlying array used by the vector.

Answer (score 1):

> aren't vectors dynamic arrays)

Conceptually yes, implementation wise, no. A vector instance is an object, of type `std::vector <sometype>`. If you want to take the address of an object like a vector instance, you need to use the address-of, aka `&`, operator. A vector is *not* the same kind of thing as a c++  array.

> Why if i write `cout<<*ptr<<endl;`, compiler gives error

Because std::vector doesn't support streaming via operator<<.

Edit:

If you actually wanted to access the internal array, you would do:

```
vector <int> v = // whatever
int * ip = &v[0];
```

or:

```
int * ip = v.data();
```

Comment: Oh yes since it'a an object INSIDE of which is implemented an array you have to use the & and the dot or -> operator to access the actual array.. did i get it right?

Comment: @Gian You only need to use those operators because you have a pointer to a vector. Mostly, you don't want to have pointers to vectors, or indeed to anything else. If you actually want to access the underlying array, see my edit.

Comment: `Because std::vector doesn't support streaming via operator<<` Or it should be "because std::cout doesn't support vector insertion"?

Comment: @:Loreto Not really, ostreams only support insertion for types in the standard library (and not for many of them). Vectors of type vector <sometype> are obviously not types in the standard library.